# When the @Published publishes the value it wraps?

Tags: swift, swiftui, publish-subscribe, combine, property-wrapper

I've got the publisher

```swift
@Published var feedData = Feed()
```

And this piece of code, which listens to it

```swift
// some View 
.onReceive(feed.$feedData) { feedData in
            if feedData.personalTasks.count > 0 {
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                    showCards = true
                }
            }
        }
```

The question is when .onRecieve will be executed? Every time feedData is accessed? Or every time any property of feedData is changed? How does this property wrapper know when *something* changes in feedData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.onReceive` will be executed every time `feedData` is changed, which is when the `Published` publisher will emit a value.

If `Feed` is a value-type, like a `struct`, then anytime any of its properties change, the value-type semantics of Swift ensure that the entire object is being changed.

If `Feed` is a reference-type - a `class`, then only when setting `feedData` to a different instance would emit a value.